# Unix KSH: Return only 1 for any error and 0 for success

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have the unix shell script, in which i have given two condition for error and non error as shown below:

**Script**: Test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

error1=ERROR
error2=FAIL

CheckError1=`grep $error1 proshell.sh | wc -l`

CheckErro2=`grep $error2 proshell.sh | wc -l`

if [ $CheckError1 -ge 1 ] then
   exit 1

elif [ $CheckError2 -ge 1 ] then
   exit 1

else
   exit 0
fi
```

**Note**: The problem is that i am not getting always 1 for any errors for exit 1.

How to get only 1 for any errors?

Comment: Please show the real code; what you've shown is not syntactically correct.  You also have a typo: `CheckErro2=` vs `$CheckError2 -ge`.  What are you getting instead of 1?  Are you getting 0?  Or is `[` complaining about a malformed condition?  But the code doesn't run, so … speculation is futile.  See also [How to debug a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/) which references Bash but the same works for Korn shell (and Bourne shell).

Comment: Also, you talk about `ksh`, but your shebang line specifies `/bin/sh`, which is most likely _not_ `ksh`.

Comment: Combine both tests with `grep -E "${error1}|${error2}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the **number of lines matched** not the **exit status of grep**.

You want to do this:

```
error1=ERROR
error2=FAIL
file-proshell.sh

if grep -q "$error1" "$file" || grep -q "$error2" "$file"; then
   exit 1
else
   exit 0
fi
```

`grep -q` suppresses output, but exits with success exit status if a match was found